# vector contains extra values beyond its size in c++

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I have a vector of a structure, and the structure is a triplet of values.

```
struct Process
{
   int64_t id, arrivalTime, burstTime;
};

vector<Process> parseInputFile(string filename, vector<Process> &vec){
  ifstream inFile;
  int64_t arrival;
  int64_t burst;
  inFile.open(filename);

    if (!inFile) {
      cerr << "Unable to open file datafile.txt";
      exit(1);   // call system to stop
    }
    for ( int64_t i = 0; i>=0; i++) {
      inFile >> arrival;
      inFile >> burst;
      if(inFile.eof()){
        inFile.close();
        cout<<"Size of vector: "<<vec.size()<<endl;
        return vec;
      }
      vec.push_back({i, arrival, burst});
    }
    return vec;

}



int main(int argc, char * const argv[]){
  string algo = argv[1];
  string filename = argv[2];
  int timeSlice;
  vector<Process> vec;

  vec = parseInputFile(filename, vec);

  for(int i = 0; i <vec.size()+10; i++){
    cout<<vec[i].arrivalTime<<" "<<vec[i].burstTime<<endl;
  }



}
```

As you can see above, in for loop, I print out 10 values beyond the size of my vector and This is what I get as output

```
1 10
3 5
5 3
0 0
51841 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

Even though my file only has the first 3 lines.
In my future code I want to be able to look up values in this vector and move them around, which will be impossible if my vector is filled with garbage. 
How do I ensure that my vector is only filled with values from the input file I give to it?

Comment: Indexing out of range is [ub](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Anything could happen. Your vector shouldn't contain any garbage. Just don't index out of bounds.

Comment: ... and to add to the multitude of problems with the shown code, the vector gets passed by value, so all changes to the values of the vector inside `parseInputFile` disappear into a big, black, dark, cold void, never to be seen again...

Comment: @cigien, will my code work fine even if I push_back, decrement values inside the vector or erase values from vector, as long as don't access values larger than vec.size()?

Comment: I can't guarantee that the code will work, that depends on doing several things correctly.

Comment: @cigien, I read that using .at(i) checks bounds. Will I be able to avoid ub if I only ever access values using vec.at(i)?

Comment: Yes, you will get a runtime exception instead, which might be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: `if(inFile.eof())` should be `if (!inFile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mention, you can't just read memory beyond your vector's allocated space and NOT expect garbage. Your RAM will look a bit like this (very simplified):

```
Address | Value
--------|-------
0x00001 | garbage
0x00002 | 1        <--- vector vec points here (vec[0])
0x00003 | 2
0x00004 | 3        <--- three elements were pushed, so vector vec ends here (vec[2])
0x00005 | garbage
```

So if you read beyond `vec[2]`, you will read random values in RAM which is undefined. That's why you see that garbage in your for loop.

By the way, if the above diagram looks foreign to you, you should probably read some C/C++ tutorials or read up on it in a book.

Lastly, I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve, but if you want to guarantee that the 10 values after your vector ends are 0, then you have to initialize those values to 0. C++ won't magically do that for you.

You can do this using `vec.reserve(N)` where N is the number of elements you want to initialize.

Also, like the comments mentioned, you should pass the vector by reference, not by value. The way you did it, the vector gets copied when it gets passed to your function, the function modifies it and returns the modified copy. Take a look at the below code, where the vector's address gets passed and the function modifies the vector directly without needing to make a copy (saves memory and is faster).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Process
{
   int64_t id, arrivalTime, burstTime;
};

// note the & sign means will pass vec by reference instead of by value
void parseInputFile(string filename, vector<Process>& vec){
  ifstream inFile;
  int64_t arrival;
  int64_t burst;
  inFile.open(filename);

    if (!inFile) {
      cerr << "Unable to open file datafile.txt";
      exit(1);   // call system to stop
    }
    for ( int64_t i = 0; i>=0; i++) {
      inFile >> arrival;
      inFile >> burst;
      if(inFile.eof()){
        inFile.close();
        cout<<"Size of vector: "<<vec.size()<<endl;
        break;
      }
      vec.push_back({i, arrival, burst});
    }
}



int main(int argc, char * const argv[]){
  string algo = argv[1];
  string filename = argv[2];
  int timeSlice;
  vector<Process> vec;

  // initialize and zero 30 elements 
  vec.reserve(30);

  // modify vec by passing it by reference
  parseInputFile(filename, vec);

  for(int i = 0; i <vec.size()+10; i++){
    cout<<vec[i].arrivalTime<<" "<<vec[i].burstTime<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the code to pass by reference. My only concern now is that I my future code. Will not access random values from RAM. Should I access my vector via vec.at(i)(since it checks the bounds) or is there a better, more optimal way of ensuring that I never check out of bounds of my vector?

Comment: Returning the vector by value is good practice (NRVO means there will be no unnecessary copy) , obviously the original code is bad for both returning it and taking it by reference!

Comment: @M.M why is returning by value good practice if you pass by ref?

Comment: @DenisShevchenko IMO you should check whether your index lies within your vector size (e.g. `i < vec.size()`) because using .at() might cause a runtime exception. If that's what you want, go for it.